# Why is renaming files with sed and mv printing '$'\r'

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, mv

I am using Ubuntu on a Windows 10 machine. I am trying to rename 5 files (file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, file4.txt, file5.txt) so that each file is replaced by Sample#_VoucherID.fastq.gz.

To do this, I haver a .csv file that has a format of `oldfile,newfile` and I am using `sed` as follows"

`sed 's/^/mv -vi /;s/,/ /;s/$//'  < File-Rename.csv | bash -e`

Whenever I run this, I instead of getting:

`Sample#_VoucherID.fastq.gz` for each file, I get `'Sample#_VoucherID.fastq.gz'$'\r'` instead. Why is this happening? If I use `mv` just in the Ubuntu terminal to rename files, I get the files renamed as I want, without the `'`,`$`,and `\` before and after the file name. If I don't use the `| bash -e` in the file and I remove the quotes, it prints:

```
mv -vi file1.txt Sample1_VoucherID.fastq.gz

mv -vi file2.txt Sample2_VoucherID.fastq.gz

mv -vi file3.txt Sample3_VoucherID.fastq.gz

mv -vi file4.txt Sample4_VoucherID.fastq.gz

mv -vi file5.txt Sample5_VoucherID.fastq.gz
```

however, it does not actually run the `mv` command. How can I rename my files without getting those extra characters?

Comment: Because the File-Rename.csv file has DOS-style `\r\n` line endings. Use `dos2unix` on it, or do `sed -e 's/\r$//' -e 'your code here'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your input file `File-Rename.csv` has Windows-style CRLF line endings instead of Unix-style `LF` - the `$'\r'` is the shell's way of representing the carriage return character.

You can "correct" you command by changing the final sed expression from `s/$//` (which doesn't actually do anything - `$` in a regular expression is a zero-length assertion that matches the end of the line, but doesn't actually consume a character) to `s/\r$//`

Alternatively, convert the input file using `dos2unix`

HOWEVER this approach to renaming files is problematic - in particular, it will fail if either the old or new name contains spaces or certain shell special characters - and even permits code injection<sup>1</sup>. Instead I'd suggest something like

```
while IFS=, read old new; do 
  mv -vi -- "$old" "$new"
done < <(sed 's/\r$//' File-Rename.csv)
```

or

```
while IFS=, read old new; do 
  echo mv -vi -- "$old" "${new%$'\r'}"
done < File-Rename.csv
```

(remove the `echo` once you are happy with the proposed commands).

Note that this approach will itself fail for certain names that are legal within the CSV format - in particular those containing quoted embedded commas (`"foo,bar",baz` for example).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>think what happens if someone enters a filename like `foo;rm *` for example</sub>

Comment: Thank you! This worked! Just for my knowledge, what did the `s/\r$\\` do? Is it saying to substitute the `CRLF` with nothing? This worked! I don't use spaces, so I used the first suggestion, but I will keep in mind the `while` code you send as well. I appreciate it!

Comment: @Justin yes that's right - `sed 's/\r$//'` matches a carriage return character `\r` anchored to the end of a line `$` and substitutes nothing in its place. You could probably safely delete *all* carriage returns (for example with `tr -d '\r'`) but the sed version is more formally correct for turning `CRLF` to `LF`

Comment: Thank you; that's really helpful because the times I have tried to use `dos2unix` it hasn't helped; so knowing alternative codes like you've given are great. I appreciate you taking the time to explain the code, too!